# Laravel: Token Mismatch Exception only on iOS (iPhone & iPad)

Tags: php, ios, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having some issues with Mobile devices, iOS specifically, when I login to my app or search for something on a form that has a token I get a **Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException** on filters.php line 88 that has

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
  if(Session::token() !== Input::get('_token')) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
  }
});
```

Code for login on the Controller:

```
    $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
        'email' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ), true);

    if($auth){
        # Redirect to intended page
        return Redirect::intended('/dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('signin')
        ->with('global-error','Incorrect email or password.');
    }
```

Form tag code on the HTML page:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL::route('signin-post') }}">
   <!-- Token is echoed like this: -->
   {{ Form::token() }}
```

Any way I can fix this? Works perfectly on PC and Android devices, if I remove that filter it works perfectly for iOS, otherwise I get the exception.

**Additional details:**

- This has happened with two different projects
- I'm using Laravel 4.2 with PHP 5.5.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It is because Safari is blocking the cookies. Set it to allow cookies and it will work.

Comment: Was stuck with this problem also and almost gave up. Your answer saved me. Thank you